# JFET Q-point for use it as resistor

Tags: resistance, jfet, quiescent, small-signal

I'm trying to use JFET as resistor.

[image]

For use it as a resistor DS voltage need to be less than Vp. Vp from datasheet of 2n4391 is equal to -VgsOff and equal to 4.0V. How I can to set scheme to view that my JFET works as a resistor?

Datasheet link: https://www.centralsemi.com/get_document.php?cmp=1&mergetype=pd&mergepath=pd&pdf_id=2n4391-4393.PDF

Comment: What is \$V_p\$? In any case \$V_{gs}\$ must be negative, i.e. V2 must be < 0V

Comment: Vp is pinch-off-voltage and equal to |VgsOff| that may be founded in datasheet. Schematic updated, V2 now is in reverse direction

Comment: https://www.vishay.com/docs/70598/70598.pdf And JFET are used as a resistor in Wien bridge oscillator. But the JFET must by work in the triode (linear) region. Hence Vsd << |Vgs|.

Comment: Q-point for the variable-resistor application should average out to zero volts. And AC amplitude can't be very high, especially when \$ R_{DS} \$ becomes large, else this resistance becomes non-linear. Your test circuit only exercises one of two quadrants. Try making V1 an AC source rather than +2V DC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many SPICE simulators are good for exploring such arrangements. Learn to exercise their plotting capabilities. Here's a LTSpice run of a common N-channel JFET that came up first (don't take this as a recommendation for use in this application).
[image: LTSPICE JFET test circuit for variable resistance sweep]
The test circuit applies a small 0.5V(peak) 1000 Hz. sine wave voltage to the drain-to-source points, where the "variable resistance" is of interest. Gate-to-source voltage is stepped through a list of DC voltages.
Current vs. voltage is plotted. An excellent result would be a set of straight lines of various slopes:
[image: Plot of I vs. V for JFET variable resistor]
For Vgs=0V, this JFET looks like an almost linear resistor of about 138 ohms.
For Vgs=-1.0V, linearity is visibly deteriorating. It is changing between about 175 - 222 ohms. For more negative gate voltages, linearity becomes worse. At these larger gate voltages, the FET is useful as a linear resistor only for very small drain-to-source AC voltages.